# Wrap Text not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a table structure like below:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="FirstDiv">
            <table>
                    <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>            
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="SecondDiv">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The structure of `FirstDiv` and `SecondDiv` are same. The `td` tag inside `FirstDiv` contains some text and I am showing the text (Text is dynamic one,it is coming from back end.) using anchor tag but if the text is more wider than 150px, it is pushing the border to right. According to requirement, there should not be any horizontal scroll bar so, I tried to wrap the text inside the anchor tag, giving styles like `word-wrap:normal`, but till now not able to fix it. Its either giving me a horizontal scroll bar or pushing the border to right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is there open tr at the end of script?  - butt.. check the overflow http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Have you applied break-word to the table cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
table {table-layout:fixed}
td {width:50%}
```